# Video Stoped Working after upgrading Msi Wind to Ubuntu Jaunty 9.04 (BadAlloc)

Tags: ubuntu, video, ubuntu-9.04

After an upgrade to Ubuntu Jaunty on my MSI wind, all video applications crashed with BadAlloc (If run from command line).

Comment: ~quack: Oops, wrong version number

Comment: just checking, thx for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution for me was to revert the intel driver and restart X with `nohup sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`

From [this wiki post](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReinhardTartler/X/RevertingIntelDriverTo2.4):

Add to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/siretart/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/siretart/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
```

Then the following Commands:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xce90d8983e731f79
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel-2.4
$ nohup sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

This fixed vlc video, and my skype webcam on my MSI wind.